# Choose among 30+ items in android

Tags: gui-design, android

Does anyone have a best practice on how to present 30+ items (numbers, say between 1 and 30) on an android screen? I thought about using a number field, but maybe it's better to make a screen with all the numbers? Or, alternatively, my goodness, a scroll list of those 35 elements with the most used first? Any best practices out there?

Comment: Try [Slider](https://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/seek-bars.html)

Comment: What do these 30 items represent? Are the numbers for each item understood by the user or they largely arbitrary?

Comment: I've seen it done as a big ol' scroll list.  That's a very sad thing to work with on the emulator since it scrolls so slow.  Actually works pretty well on the hardware though, "feels" easier to use than the classic number picker.

Answer (score 1):

Android provides a widget which allows the user to select a number from a predefined range.

The number picker's appearance depends on the current theme.

[image: numberpicker]

For more information, see the [NumberPicker reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) in the Android Developer docs.